# How to imprint logo into STL

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials, uv, export

[image: Coin]

Hello, I have statements and questions. I want to imprint my logo into the coins surface but whenever I upload the filed to a 3D viewer it ends up blank. How do I fix this? Also is there a way to make the engraving go deeper into the coin? One more question. The backside of the coin has a mirror of the front image that is larger than the front. How do I increase the surface coverage of the logo and apply different engravings to each side of the coin? Thank you for your help, gotten this far so I figured I could get farther with more help lol

Comment: Please add the image directly into your question rather than linking to an external site which may not exist in future. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 0):

To answer you first question: When you importing STL hit , on numpad (key next to 0) or if you dont have numpad hit `tilda` key above TAB and chose `View Selected` and check in right upper corner do you have new object beside Camera, Cube and Light

Second: Yes you can engrave deeper by using "Boolean" modifier

Third: Go to edit mode and delete "mirrored mesh" hit "F" and use Boolean modifier to "engrave" new object on to it

Comment: Instructions unclear for first answer. "When you import STL" I am not understanding, do you mean importing the image to blender? Can I use, that isn't on the num pad if I don't have a numpad? "Do you have new object beside Camera, Cube and Light Second" Is this in blender or the app I'm uploading to?

Comment: @splashworks no I don't mean importing image where did you read that ? You was asking how to import .stl. I updated answer if you don't have numpad hit "tilda" key above "TAB" and choose `View Selected`. And for your last question yes I meant in blender no app which you using

Comment: 1.) Yes, https://imgur.com/svNyik3 (here's a picture) I have a new object beside the camera, cube, and light. I meant when I the mask wasn't exporting with the model. 3.) I confused myself. I assumed when I didn't see the option to delete the mirrored mesh, or am I in the wrong category? I didn't see the option. (Here's a picture of options) https://imgur.com/CuGeTsI

Comment: @splashworks To delete mirrored mesh go it to Edit mode by pressing "TAB" and there select mesh which you want to delete

Comment: I don't see the mirrored mesh. Whenever I try to select the mirrored image, it gives me 0 vertices mirrored. Is that plain English for nothing is mirrored? Also, I think I need to clarify.  I put the logo in material wrap on a coin and I wanted to convert it into an engraving. Do I need to delete the wrap? I can't delete the side without deleting the face of the coin.